# How to add element after label before input with simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to add a character counter to an app I am helping with but the app uses simple form gem for the page i need to work with. The Gem seems pretty cool expect that it auto generates the html and i need to figure out how to add my custom div after the label and the input so i can add the character count and change it as it goes.

I can do this with jquery but i am wanting to do an initial hard coded count for initial load just in case the user has an old browser without javascript.

```
<%= simple_form_for @organization do |f| %>  
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :projects do |project| %>
     <div class="row">
        <%= project.input :description, :placeholder => 'What does your project do?', input_html: { class: 'project-description' }, :maxlength => 255 %>
    <% end %>
```

I want to add the character limit to the description tag.